# Как считать значение Spinner за пределами onItemSelected?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Всем привет, я новичок в Android. 
У меня есть два Spinner и в зависимости от выбора переходим к действию. 
Я пытаюсь получить выбранный результат в виде строки. В методе onItemSelected результат выдает правильно. Но как только я туже строку пытаюсь вывести за пределами этого метода он выдает результат Null. 
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться

```
public class LengthActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Spinner lengthLeft, lengthRight;
String textMenuLeft= "";
String textMenuRight= "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_length);

    Spinner lengthLeft = findViewById(R.id.lengthLeft);
    Spinner lengthRight = findViewById(R.id.lengthRight);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterLeft = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.lengthList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    adapterLeft.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    lengthLeft.setAdapter(adapterLeft);
    lengthRight.setAdapter(adapterLeft);

    lengthLeft.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    textMenuLeft =  "Миллиметр";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textMenuLeft = "Сантиметр";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textMenuLeft = "Метр";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    textMenuLeft = "Километр";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    textMenuLeft = "Дюйм";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    textMenuLeft = "Фут";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    textMenuLeft = "Ярд";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    textMenuLeft = "Миля";
                    break;
            }
           //Вот этот результат выдает правильно
            System.out.println("choose in left in method: " + textMenuLeft);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

 //А вот тут считает что строка TextMenuLeft ноль!!
   System.out.println("choose in left out: " + textMenuLeft);

}
```

Comment: Вам нужно осознать, что код выполняется не построчно подряд, а в последовательности, зависящей от логики. В `onCreate` выбор ещё не сделан, он будет сделан когда-нибудь потом - естественно здесь переменной `textMenuLeft` ещё ничего не присвоено. Нужно создать метод - _"переход к действию"_ и вызывать его в `onItemSelected`, где у Вас выдает правильный результат.

Comment: И наверняка Вам нужно сделать какое-то дефолтное поведение - для этого нужно сразу при объявлении присвоить строке значение по-умолчанию (например, `"Миллиметр"`) и плясать уже от него.

Comment: У вас есть член класса Spinner lengthLeft а в методе onCreate вы скрываете его объявляя переменную с тем же именем: Spinner lengthLeft = findViewById(R.id.lengthLeft); надо lengthLeft = findViewById(R.id.lengthLeft); Удачи.